# .net arcobjects delete point feature by one of the attribute value

Tags: arcobjects, point, delete

What I want is to delete a feature by objectID,  currently I have got the objectID of the related feature, but I have no idea how to delete the feature, can anybody give me some advice?

The following is what I have now.

```
Public Sub RemovePoint(ByVal lpCreatWS As IWorkspace, ByVal lpFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer,  ByVal lsLayerName As String, ByVal lpFeatCursor As IFeatureCursor)


Dim lpCreatVer As IVersion
Dim lpVersionEdit As IVersionEdit
Dim lpWorkSpaceEdit As IWorkspaceEdit
Dim lpVerFC As IFeatureClass

lpCreatVer = lpCreatWS
lpCreatVer.RefreshVersion() 

lpVersionEdit = lpCreatWS
lpWorkSpaceEdit = lpCreatWS

Try

      lpFeature = lpFeatCursor.NextFeature

      lpWorkSpaceEdit.StartEditing(True)

      Do Until lpFeature Is Nothing

            lpVerFC = lpObjSDEUtils.GetFeatureClass(lpCreatWS, lsLayerName)
            lpVerFeat = lpVerFC.GetFeature(lpFeature.OID) 

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Delete method in IFeature Interface.

```
IFeature.Delete()
```

For your code:

```
...
lpVerFeat = lpVerFC.GetFeature(lpFeature.OID) 
lpVerFeat.Delete()
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Farid, but I found I even got error on lpVerFeat = lpVerFC.GetFeature(lpFeature.OID). I got the NullReferenceException error on this line.

Comment: Hi Farid, this error won't occur, but I have another issue when I tried to refresh a version. I will create a new thread to the question, thank you very much!